# Type safe Scala Builder pattern with special rules

Tags: scala, builder, subtyping

I'm trying to create a type safe builder of a case class , where its params can be of following types:

1. required
2. optional
3. required but mutually exclusive ->
   a. ex. lets say I've 3 params: (param1), (param2, param3). If I have param1, I cannot set param2 or param3. If I can set both param2 and param3, but I cannot set param1
4. optional but mutually exclusive -> same logic as above but these are optional params. That is optionally I can set either param1 or (param2 and param3).

I figured how to get required and optional cases, but cannot get case 3 and 4.
Any ideas how to proceed.

These checks can be done at runtime, but I want these set of rules being implemented at compile time

```
case class Person(name: String, /*required*/
                  address: String, /*optional*/
                  city: String, /* reqd exclusive*/
                  county: String, /* reqd exclusive*/
                  state: String /* reqd exclusive*/,
                  ssn: String, /* optional exclusive*/
                  insurance: String, /* opt exclusive*/
                  passport: String /* opt exclusive*/)
// where (city) and (county, state) are required but are mutually exclusive
// (ssn) and (insurance, passport) are optional but are mutually exclusive. 
// If I set passport, I've to set insurance

sealed trait PersonInfo
object PersonInfo {
  sealed trait Empty extends PersonInfo
  sealed trait Name extends PersonInfo
  sealed trait Address extends PersonInfo
  type Required = Empty with Name with Address
}

case class PersonBuilder[T <: PersonInfo]
(name: String = "", address: String = "", city: String = "", county: String = "", 
  state: String = "", ssn: String = "", insurance: String = "",passport: String ="") {

  def withName(name: String): PersonBuilder[T with PersonInfo.Name] =
    this.copy(name = name)

  def withTask(address: String): PersonBuilder[T with PersonInfo.Address ] =
    this.copy(address = address)

  def withCity(city: String): PersonBuilder[T] =
    this.copy(city = city)

  def withCountry(county: String): PersonBuilder[T] =
    this.copy(county = county)

  def withState(state: String): PersonBuilder[T] =
    this.copy(state = state)

  def withSsn(ssn: String): PersonBuilder[T] =
    this.copy(ssn = ssn)

  def withInsurance(insurance: String): PersonBuilder[T] =
    this.copy(insurance = insurance)

  def withPassport(passport: String): PersonBuilder[T] =
    this.copy(passport = passport)

  def build(implicit ev: T =:= PersonInfo.Required): Person =
    Person(name, address, city, county, state, ssn, insurance, passport)
}
```

here's the build

```
val testPerson = PersonBuilder[PersonInfo.Empty]()
    .withName("foo")
    .withSsn("bar")
```

Comment: Rather than a builder I would just use an ADT to represent the invariants.

Comment: even with ADT, how could I account for the required exclusive and optional exclusive set of rules

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in a comment, if creating a builder is not a hard requirement, a viable choice could be to make those requirements explicit in the types, using sum types for exclusive choices and `Option`s for optional ones, as in the following example:

```
sealed abstract class Location extends Product with Serializable {
  def value: String
}

object Location {
  final case class City(value: String) extends Location
  final case class County(value: String) extends Location
  final case class State(value: String) extends Location
}

sealed abstract class Identity extends Product with Serializable {
  def value: String
}

object Identity {
  final case class Ssn(value: String) extends Identity
  final case class Insurance(value: String) extends Identity
  final case class Passport(value: String) extends Identity
}

final case class Person(
    name: String,
    address: Option[String],
    location: Location,
    identity: Option[Identity],
)
```

Scala 3 further introduced `enum`s which makes the definition more compact and readable:

```
enum Location(value: String) {
  case City(value: String) extends Location(value)
  case County(value: String) extends Location(value)
  case State(value: String) extends Location(value)
}

enum Identity(value: String) {
  case Ssn(value: String) extends Identity(value)
  case Insurance(value: String) extends Identity(value)
  case Passport(value: String) extends Identity(value)
}

final case class Person(
    name: String,
    address: Option[String],
    location: Location,
    identity: Option[Identity],
)
```

And making `Option`s default to `None` you get a very similar experience to custom-made builders without any additional code:

```
final case class Person(
    name: String,
    location: Location,
    address: Option[String] = None,
    identity: Option[Identity] = None,
)

Person("Alice", Location.City("New York"))
  .copy(identity = Some(Identity.Ssn("123456")))
```

Which you can further refine very easily:

```
final case class Person(
    name: String,
    location: Location,
    address: Option[String] = None,
    identity: Option[Identity] = None
) {

  def withAddress(address: String): Person =
    this.copy(address = Some(address))

  def withIdentity(identity: Identity): Person =
    this.copy(identity = Some(identity))

}

Person("Alice", Location.City("New York")).withIdentity(Identity.Ssn("123456"))
```

You can play around with this code [here on Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/stefanobaghino/kQidhnc5RxepcLC1X1m5nQ/5).

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I'd love to accept this as the answer,  however this still doesnot meet the requirement of required/optional exclusive condition. If an user provides Identity.Insurance, he needs to provide Identity.Passport, and this needs to checked at compile time, somehow.

Comment: Then you can probably group together `Identity.Insurance` and `Identity.Passport` in a single `case` of the `enum`, right?